# Improve notification logic for adding or removing tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app where users are notified via email when an admin changes their profile...tags added/removed, address change...ect. Here is the existing code...

```
def event_notification
    if self.creator != self.user
      case self.event_code
      when ADDED_TAGS, REMOVED_TAGS
        Notification.create(notifiable: self, created_by: self.created_by, recipient_id: self.user_id, delivery_time: 1.minute.from_now )
      when ADDRESS_CHANGED
      ...
```

The issue we are having is when someone modifies the users tags, they typically add and remove multiple tags in a relatively short period of time. A notification (email) is generated for each added or removed tag. I'd like to modify this event_notification method so if a tag is add/removed within a given time frame (say 5 minutes), then only a single notification is created.

I'm thinking I could put some kind of flag inside the ADDED_TAGS, REMOVED_TAGS case where the notification is only created once in a 5 minute time frame. However, the logic is escaping me, and looking for some ideas, or a different way to look at this.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create_user_event_notification
    if self.creator != self.user
      case self.event_code
      when ADDED_TAGS, REMOVED_TAGS
        last_notification = Notification.where(recipient_id: self.user_id, notification_type: notification_type).last
        unless last_notification.nil?
          if Time.now - last_notification.created_at > 300 #5 minutes
            Notification.create(notifiable: self, created_by: self.created_by, recipient_id: self.user_id,
                            notification_type: Notification::TAG_EDIT, delivery_time: 1.minute.from_now )
          end
        end
      when CHANGED_VACATION_STATUS
        Notification.create(notifiable: self, created_by: self.created_by, recipient_id: self.user_id,
                            notification_type: Notification::VACATION_EDIT, delivery_time: 1.minute.from_now )
      when ADDED_LOCATION, REMOVED_LOCATION, ADDED_COUNTY, REMOVED_COUNTY
        Notification.create(notifiable: self, created_by: self.created_by, recipient_id: self.user_id,
                            notification_type: Notification::LOCATION_EDIT, delivery_time: 1.minute.from_now )
      end
    end
  end
```